# my program has a segmentation fault

Tags: c

My program gives a segmentation fault, and I have no idea where it is.
Here's the relevant code. the program generates a tree from a list using the inorder and postorder traversal of the tree.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

typedef struct btreenode{
    struct btreenode *rightchild;
    struct btreenode *leftchild; 
    float val;
    int data;
}Node;


struct btreenode* Treebuilding(float *, int *, int , int, float *, int *, int, int);
struct btreenode* cargar_arbol(char *);
struct btreenode* new_node(int, float);

int main(){
    FILE *fp, *fap;
    char cmd[257], par[257];
    int num; float val;
    struct btreenode *root;
    root = NULL;
    if ((fp = fopen("rutina.dat", "r")) == 0){
        printf("Error al cargar el archivo rutina.dat\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fap =fopen("output.dat", "w");
    while(fscanf(fp, "%[^ \n]", cmd)!= 0){
        if(strcmp("Cargar", cmd)==0){
            fscanf(fp, "%s", par);
            root = cargar_arbol(par);
            if(root != NULL)    
                fprintf(fap, "Datos Cargados\n");
            else
                fprintf(fap, "No se pudo cargar datos\n"); 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

struct btreenode* Treebuilding(float InOrder[],int inorderName[], int instart, int inend,float PostOrder[], int postorderName[], int poststart,int  postend){
    int i;
    if (instart > inend|| poststart > postend){
        return NULL;
    }
    int rootname = postorderName[postend];  
    struct btreenode* root = new_node(postorderName[postend],PostOrder[postend]); 
    int k =0;

    for (i=0; i < inend; i++){
        if(inorderName[i] == rootname){
            k=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    root->leftchild = Treebuilding (InOrder, inorderName, instart, k-1, PostOrder,postorderName, poststart, poststart+k-(instart+1));
    root->rightchild= Treebuilding (InOrder,inorderName, k+1, inend, PostOrder,postorderName, poststart+k-instart, postend);

    return root;
}

struct btreenode* cargar_arbol(char *nombre){
    FILE* fp; int size, *inorderName, *postorderName;
    float *inorder, *postorder; int i;
    if ((fp = fopen(nombre, "r")) == 0){
        printf("Error al cargar %c", nombre);
        return NULL;
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &size);
    inorder = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*size);
    inorderName = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    postorder = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*size);
    postorderName = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);

    int instart = 0;
    int inend = size-1;
    int poststart = 0;
    int postend = size -1;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        fscanf(fp, "Liceo %d | %f", &inorderName[i],  &inorder[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<size ; i++){
        fscanf(fp, "Liceo %d | %f", &postorderName[i],  &postorder[i]);
    }
    return Treebuilding(inorder, inorderName, instart, inend, postorder, postorderName, poststart, postend);
}
```

gdb says it is in the function treebuilding(), but I fail to see the exact location.

Comment: You're already using gdb.  How about stepping through execution line by line until you see exactly where you get the error?

Comment: If you want someone to debug your code you will at least have to provide a data set that leads to the error, and a MCVE

Comment: Segmentation faults are usually very easy to find by just single stepping. The line where the program crashes either contains the bug, or otherwise the bug is related to the variables used on that line. Also, since others might have to read your code, for example when you are asking for help on SO, _always_ give identifiers English names and write all comments in English (this coming from another non-native English speaker).

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can enable core-dumps via the `ulimit -c unlimited` command. Compile your program with debug symbols (`gdb -g -O0`), then execute your program and wait for the crash.

With the core dump you can analyze the crash, using `gdb -c core <program>`. The gdb command `bt` shows the backtrace of the crash and voila, sourcefile and line of the error show up.